# How to convert a JPA OneToMany relationship to DTO

Tags: java, jpa, dto

I have a class `Plan` in which there is a list of `Activity`. The `Activity` class has a reference to a single `Plan`. Hence there is a **OneToMany** relationship like this:

```
@Entity
public class Plan {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Plan")
    private List<Activity> activities;
}

@Entity
public class Activity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "PLAN_ID")
    private Plan plan;
}
```

I need to convert them to DTOs to be sent to presentation layer. So I have an assembler class to simply convert domain objects to POJO.

```
public class PlanAssembler {

    public static PlanDTO makeDTO(Plan p) {

    PlanDTO result = new PlanDTO();
    result.setProperty(p.getProperty);
    ... 

    for (Activity a: p.getActivity()) {

     // Here I need to iterate over each activity to convert it to DTO
     // But in ActivityAssembler, I also need PlanDTO

    }
```

As you can see, in `PlanAssembler`, I need to iterate over all activities and convert them to `ActivityDTO` but the trouble is, in `ActivityAssembler` I also need the `PlanDTO` to construct the `ActivityDTO`. It's gonna be an **infinite loop**. How can I sort this out?

Please help.

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like dozer to convert your POJO's to DTOs? they have logic avoinding this kind of backreferences: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/faq.html#infinite-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be an infinite loop because you have to use the PlanDTO object result which you have just created before the loop. See the code below.

**Note :** Still I suggest to go for a framework which will do this stuff for you.

```
public class PlanAssembler {

    public static PlanDTO makeDTO(Plan p) {

    PlanDTO result = new PlanDTO();
    result.setProperty(p.getProperty);
    ... 

    for (Activity a: p.getActivity()) {

      ActivityDTO activityDTO = new ActivityDTO();
     // Here I need to iterate over each activity to convert it to DTO
     // But in ActivityAssembler, I also need PlanDTO

     //Code to convert Activity to ActivityDTO.

      activityDTO.setPlan(result);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But the `reault` here is a `PlanDTO` and `Activity` can only have `Plan` associated with them. Not `PlanDTO`.

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer, actually Activity is also supposed to be converted to a DTO and that DTO should be pointing to PlanDTO.

Comment: One thing, I do have another assembler specifically for `Activity`. It's called `ActivityAssembler`. Do you thing it's better to send the just created `PlanDTO` as parameter to `ActivityAssembler` and set it there?

Comment: Yes you have to send it to ActivityAssembler as a parameter, but it will be messy once your domain model will increase that's why I suggested to go for a library/framework to do that.

Comment: Thanks again. No option to use a library here. At least for now but I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Now if you really want to sort things out on your own:

1) In the mapper class you could define implement mappers resolving this issue by making them unidirectional. With methods like
`MapPlanWithActivities()`, `MapPlan()`, `MapActivitiesWithPlan()` and `MapActivities()`. this way you could know what data you need and according to what function you use you know when to stop the recursion.

2) The other (much) more complex solution would be to solve the issue by logic and detect the loop. You can for instance define an annotation for that case as Jackson Library does. for that you will have to use some java reflection. [See Java Reflection here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

3) the easiest way would be to use Dozer as said in my comment:[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

### Table relationships

Let's assume we have the following `post` and `post_comment` tables, which form a one-to-many relationship via the `post_id` Foreign Key column in the `post_comment` table.

[image: The post and post_comment tables used for the JPA DTO projection]

### Fetching a one-to-many DTO projection with JPA and Hibernate

Considering we have a use case that only requires fetching the `id` and `title` columns from the `post` table, as well as the `id` and `review` columns from the `post_comment` tables, we could use the following JPQL query to fetch the required projection:

```
select p.id as p_id, 
       p.title as p_title,
       pc.id as pc_id, 
       pc.review as pc_review
from PostComment pc
join pc.post p
order by pc.id
```

When running the projection query above, we get the following results:

```
| p.id | p.title                           | pc.id | pc.review                             |
|------|-----------------------------------|-------|---------------------------------------|
| 1    | High-Performance Java Persistence | 1     | Best book on JPA and Hibernate!       |
| 1    | High-Performance Java Persistence | 2     | A must-read for every Java developer! |
| 2    | Hypersistence Optimizer           | 3     | It's like pair programming with Vlad! |
```

However, we don't want to use a tabular-based `ResultSet` or the default `List<Object[]>`JPA or Hibernate query projection. We want to transform the aforementioned query result set to a `List` of `PostDTO` objects, each such object having a `comments` collection containing all the associated `PostCommentDTO` objects:

[image: The PostDTO and PostCommentDTO used for DTO projection]

We can use a Hibernate `ResultTransformer`, as illustrated by the following example:

```
List<PostDTO> postDTOs = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select p.id as p_id, 
           p.title as p_title,
           pc.id as pc_id, 
           pc.review as pc_review
    from PostComment pc
    join pc.post p
    order by pc.id
    """)
.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
.setResultTransformer(new PostDTOResultTransformer())
.getResultList();

assertEquals(2, postDTOs.size());
assertEquals(2, postDTOs.get(0).getComments().size());
assertEquals(1, postDTOs.get(1).getComments().size());
```

The `PostDTOResultTransformer` is going to define the mapping between the `Object[]` projection and the `PostDTO` object containing the `PostCommentDTO` child DTO objects:

```
public class PostDTOResultTransformer 
        implements ResultTransformer {

    private Map<Long, PostDTO> postDTOMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(
            Object[] tuple, 
            String[] aliases) {
            
        Map<String, Integer> aliasToIndexMap = aliasToIndexMap(aliases);
        
        Long postId = longValue(tuple[aliasToIndexMap.get(PostDTO.ID_ALIAS)]);

        PostDTO postDTO = postDTOMap.computeIfAbsent(
            postId, 
            id -> new PostDTO(tuple, aliasToIndexMap)
        );
        
        postDTO.getComments().add(
            new PostCommentDTO(tuple, aliasToIndexMap)
        );

        return postDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public List transformList(List collection) {
        return new ArrayList<>(postDTOMap.values());
    }
}
```

The `aliasToIndexMap` is just a small utility that allows us to build a `Map` structure that associates the column aliases and the index where the column value is located in the `Object[]` `tuple` array:

```
public  Map<String, Integer> aliasToIndexMap(
        String[] aliases) {
    
    Map<String, Integer> aliasToIndexMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++) {
        aliasToIndexMap.put(aliases[i], i);
    }
    
    return aliasToIndexMap;
}
```

The `postDTOMap` is where we are going to store all `PostDTO` entities that, in the end, will be returned by the query execution. The reason we are using the `postDTOMap` is that the parent rows are duplicated in the SQL query result set for each child record.

The `computeIfAbsent` method allows us to create a `PostDTO` object only if there is no existing `PostDTO` reference already stored in the `postDTOMap`.

The `PostDTO` class has a constructor that can set the `id` and `title` properties using the dedicated column aliases:

```
public class PostDTO {

    public static final String ID_ALIAS = "p_id";
    
    public static final String TITLE_ALIAS = "p_title";

    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private List<PostCommentDTO> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    public PostDTO(
            Object[] tuples, 
            Map<String, Integer> aliasToIndexMap) {
            
        this.id = longValue(tuples[aliasToIndexMap.get(ID_ALIAS)]);
        this.title = stringValue(tuples[aliasToIndexMap.get(TITLE_ALIAS)]);
    }

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The `PostCommentDTO` is built in a similar fashion:

```
public class PostCommentDTO {

    public static final String ID_ALIAS = "pc_id";
    
    public static final String REVIEW_ALIAS = "pc_review";

    private Long id;

    private String review;

    public PostCommentDTO(
            Object[] tuples, 
            Map<String, Integer> aliasToIndexMap) {
        this.id = longValue(tuples[aliasToIndexMap.get(ID_ALIAS)]);
        this.review = stringValue(tuples[aliasToIndexMap.get(REVIEW_ALIAS)]);
    }

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

That's it!

Using the `PostDTOResultTransformer`, the SQL result set can be transformed into a hierarchical DTO projection, which is much convenient to work with, especially if it needs to be marshalled as a JSON response:

```
postDTOs = {ArrayList}, size = 2
  0 = {PostDTO} 
    id = 1L
    title = "High-Performance Java Persistence"
    comments = {ArrayList}, size = 2
      0 = {PostCommentDTO} 
        id = 1L
        review = "Best book on JPA and Hibernate!"
      1 = {PostCommentDTO} 
        id = 2L
        review = "A must read for every Java developer!"
  1 = {PostDTO} 
    id = 2L
    title = "Hypersistence Optimizer"
    comments = {ArrayList}, size = 1
      0 = {PostCommentDTO} 
       id = 3L
       review = "It's like pair programming with Vlad!"
```

Comment: This seems to be a quite cumbersome workaround for a such simple case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

A mapping for your model could look as simple as the following

```
@EntityView(Plan.class)
interface PlanDTO {
  @IdMapping
  Long getId();
  String getName();
  List<ActivityDTO> getActivities();
}
@EntityView(Activity.class)
interface ActivityDTO {
  @IdMapping
  Long getId();
  String getName();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`PlanDTOdto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, PlanDTO.class, id);`

But the Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-features

The biggest benefit of this is, that this approach will only fetch what you define through the getter definitions in your entity views, whereas other approaches usually fetch too much data and/or require a lot of boilerplate.