# How to convert DTO to Entity oneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, dto

I have four classes (Project, supplyRequest, Product and SupplyRequestProduct), SupplyRequestProduct is an association between SupplyRequest and product with additional attributes. All CRUD methods work fine for those classes.
But I have an issue when I want to create a new SupplyRequest object. I got this error in the console

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.mmalki.spingboot.model.SupplyRequestProduct.hashCode(SupplyRequestProduct.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.mmalki.spingboot.mapping.SupplyRequestMapperImpl.supplyRequestProductDTOSetToSupplyRequestProductSet(SupplyRequestMapperImpl.java:152) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mmalki.spingboot.mapping.SupplyRequestMapperImpl.convertToEntity(SupplyRequestMapperImpl.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mmalki.spingboot.web.SupplyRequestController.saveProduct(SupplyRequestController.java:61) ~[classes/:na]`

I check in similar questions like that one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21581696/5857569)  but didn't help
This is My code:

SupplyRequest Entity

```
@Entity
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @ToString
@Where(clause = "DELETED = 0")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class SupplyRequest extends AuditModel {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String reference;
    private LocalDate dueDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id",nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)

    @JsonManagedReference
    private Project project;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplyRequest",fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<SupplyRequestProduct> supplyRequestProducts;

    public SupplyRequest(String reference, LocalDate dueDate, Project project, SupplyRequestProduct... supplyRequestProducts ) {

        this.reference = reference;
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
        this.project = project;
        for (SupplyRequestProduct supplyRequestProduct : supplyRequestProducts )
            supplyRequestProduct.setSupplyRequest(this);
        this.supplyRequestProducts = Stream.of(supplyRequestProducts).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

SupplyRequestProduct Entity

```
@Entity
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class SupplyRequestProduct implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Min(1)
    private int quantity;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "supply_request_id")
    private SupplyRequest supplyRequest;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SupplyRequestProduct)) return false;
        SupplyRequestProduct that = (SupplyRequestProduct) o;
        return Objects.equals(supplyRequest.getReference(), that.supplyRequest.getReference()) &&
                Objects.equals(product.getReference(), that.product.getReference()) &&
                Objects.equals(quantity, that.quantity);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(supplyRequest.getReference(), product.getReference(), quantity);
    }

    public SupplyRequestProduct(int quantity, Product product) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.product = product;
    }

    public void setSupplyRequest(SupplyRequest supplyRequest) {
        this.supplyRequest = supplyRequest;
    }
}
```

SupplyRequestProductDTO

```
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @EqualsAndHashCode
public class SupplyRequestProductDTO {
    private Long id;
    private int quantity;
    private ProductDTO productDTO;
    private SupplyRequestDTO supplyRequestDTO;
}
```

SupplyRequestMapper

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE,componentModel = "spring")
public interface SupplyRequestMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "reference",target = "reference")
    @Mapping(source = "dueDate",target = "dueDate")
    @Mapping(source = "creationDate",target = "creationDate")
    @Mapping(source = "project",target = "projectDTO")
    @Mapping(source = "supplyRequestProducts",target = "supplyRequestProductsDTO")
    SupplyRequestDTO convertToDTO(SupplyRequest supplyRequest);

    List<SupplyRequestDTO> convertToListDTO(Iterable<SupplyRequest> supplyRequests);

    @Mapping(source = "reference",target = "reference")
    @Mapping(source = "dueDate",target = "dueDate")
    @Mapping(source = "creationDate",target = "creationDate")
    @Mapping(source = "projectDTO",target = "project")
    @Mapping(source = "supplyRequestProductsDTO",target = "supplyRequestProducts")
    SupplyRequest convertToEntity(SupplyRequestDTO supplyRequestDTO);
}
```

SupplyRequestProductMapper

```
    @Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE,componentModel = "spring")

public interface SupplyRequestProductMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "quantity",target = "quantity")
    @Mapping(source = "supplyRequest",target = "supplyRequestDTO")
    @Mapping(source = "product",target = "productDTO")
    SupplyRequestProductDTO convertToDTO(SupplyRequestProduct supplyRequestProduct);

    List<SupplyRequestProductDTO> convertToListDTO(Iterable<SupplyRequestProduct> supplyRequestProducts);

    @Mapping(source = "quantity",target = "quantity")
    @Mapping(source = "supplyRequestDTO",target = "supplyRequest")
    @Mapping(source = "productDTO",target = "product")
    SupplyRequestProduct convertToEntity(SupplyRequestProductDTO supplyRequestProductDTO);
}
```

SupplyRequestControoler

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/supply-requests")
public class SupplyRequestController {

    @Autowired
    private ISupplyRequestService supplyRequestService;

    @Autowired
    private SupplyRequestMapper supplyRequestMapper;

    @RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Long> saveProduct(@RequestBody SupplyRequestDTO supplyRequestDTO) throws RecordNotFoundException {

        SupplyRequest supplyRequest = supplyRequestMapper.convertToEntity(supplyRequestDTO);

        SupplyRequest supplyRequest1 = supplyRequestService.save(supplyRequest);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(supplyRequest1.getId(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And my post request has this data:

```
{
  "reference": "SPR-002",
  "dueDate": "2020-05-17",
  "creationDate": "2020-05-17",
  "projectDTO": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Project",
    "description": "Project 1",
    "creationDate": "2020-04-23"
  },
  "supplyRequestProductsDTO": [
    {
      "quantity": 4,
      "productDTO": {
        "id": 1,
        "reference": "PRT-001",
        "title": "Product 1",
        "description": "Product",
        "unite": "u",
        "price": 300,
        "quantity": 300,
        "creationDate": "2020-04-23"
      }
    },
    {
      "quantity": 6,
      "productDTO": {
        "id": 2,
        "reference": "PRT-002",
        "title": "Product 2",
        "description": "Product",
        "unite": "u",
        "price": 300,
        "quantity": 300,
        "creationDate": "2020-04-23"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that the problem showed when I want to convert supplyRequestProductsDTO to supplyRequestProducts but I don't know why.
Please help.